# InPlace Grid Edit, Cancel fails

Tags: knockout.js

I am following this blog to create the inplace grid edit.

http://blog.ryanvanderpol.com/knockout-edit-data-grid/

Everything else works ok except the Cancel button still updates the UI with new value.

How do I fix that? Hpw do I get the old value and update the field with original value when user clicks cancel?

Thanks!

```
My Object structure is :

class Tour
{
    tourSeriesName: string;
    year: string;
    tourSeriesDepartures: Array<{
        departureGroupName: string;
        departures: Array<{
            tourName: string;
            departureCode: string;
            isActive: boolean;
            tourId: number;
            tourDepartureId: number;
            assignedCoaches: Array<{
                coachName: string;
                seats: number;
                seatsAvailable: number;
                isExtensionCoach: boolean;
                resourceInventoryId: number;
                resourceScheduleId: number
            }>;


        }>;

 }>;
So something like this:


    <div id="departure-container" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: TourSeriesDepartures().length>0">


            <table class="table" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Series Departure</th>
                    <th>Main Coach Seats</th>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: currentPage }"></tbody>


            </table>

        </div>

    </body>


    <script id="itemsTmpl" type="text/html">
        <!-- ko foreach: Departures -->

        <tr>

            <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
            <td style="vertical-align:middle" data-bind="text: $parent.DepartureGroupName,attr: { rowspan: $parent.Departures().length }"></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: $parent.Departures().length }">
                <!-- ko if: $data.AssignedCoaches().length > 0 -->
                <span data-bind="text: (($data.AssignedCoaches()[0].Seats) ? $data.AssignedCoaches()[0].Seats : '?')" ></span>
                <!-- /ko -->

            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->


            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: TourName "></span>
                <span data-bind="text: DepartureCode"></span>
            </td>
            <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
            <td class="buttons" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: $parent.Departures().length }" style="vertical-align:middle">
                <span>
                    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.edit"  title="edit"> Edit </button>
                </span>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->

        </tr>

        <!-- /ko -->
    </script>

    <script id="editTmpl" type="text/html">


        <!-- ko foreach: Departures -->

        <tr > @*data-bind="click: $root.selectItem"*@

            <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
            <td style="vertical-align:middle" data-bind="text: $parent.DepartureGroupName,attr: { rowspan: $parent.Departures().length }"></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: $parent.Departures().length }">
                <!-- ko if: $data.AssignedCoaches().length > 0 -->
                <span><input data-bind="value: (($data.AssignedCoaches()[0].Seats) ? $data.AssignedCoaches()[0].Seats : '?'), event: { blur: $root.here}" required /></span>
                <!-- /ko -->

            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->


            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: TourName "></span>
                <span data-bind="text: DepartureCode"></span>
            </td>
            <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 -->
            <td class="buttons" data-bind="attr: { rowspan: $parent.Departures().length }" style="vertical-align:middle">
                <span>
                    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.save"  title="save"> Save </button>
                    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.cancel"  title="cancel">Cancel</button>
                </span>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->

        </tr>

        <!-- /ko -->




    </script>

    var viewModel = function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
            }
            var self = this;
            self.TourSeriesDepartures = ko.observableArray([]);


            self.selectedItem = ko.observable("");


            self.saveMe = function (d) {
                var resourceScheduleId = d.AssignedCoaches()[0].ResourceScheduleId();
                var seats = d.AssignedCoaches()[0].Seats();
                //alert("in save" + this);
                //viewModel.selectedItem(this);
                $.ajax({
                    //url: "SaveTour",
                    url: "SaveTour/?seats=" + seats + "&rsID=" + resourceScheduleId,
                    data: ko.toJSON({ tour: ko.toJS(self.selectedItem) }),
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (result)
                    { alert(result) }
                });

            }

            // trying in place editing

            self.selectedItemCache = ko.observable();


            self.templateToUse = function (item) {
                return self.selectedItem() === item.Departures()[0] ? 'editTmpl' : 'itemsTmpl';
            };

            self.edit = function (item) {

                self.selectedItem(item);
                self.selectedItemCache(ko.mapping.toJS(item));
            };

            self.cancel = function () {


                if (self.selectedItemCache) {
                    var item = self.selectedItem();
                    //var index = self.list.indexOf(item);
                    //self.list.splice(index, 1, self.selectedBackup);

                }

                self.selectedItem(null);

            };

            self.save = function () {
                var item = self.selectedItem();
                var resourceScheduleId = item.AssignedCoaches()[0].ResourceScheduleId();
                var seats = item.AssignedCoaches()[0].Seats();
                //alert("in save" + this);
                //viewModel.selectedItem(this);
                $.ajax({
                    //url: "SaveTour",
                    url: "SaveTour/?seats=" + seats + "&rsID=" + resourceScheduleId,
                    data: ko.toJSON({ tour: ko.toJS(self.selectedItem) }),
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (result)
                    {
                        alert(result);
                        self.selectedItem(null);
                    }
                });
            }



            self.selectItem = function () {
                //self.selectedItem(this);
            }


            self.getDataFromServer = function (t) {
                var tour = $("#tourCode").val();
                var year = $("#year").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Search/?tour=" + tour + "&year=" + year ,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {

                        ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self);
                        self.page(0);

                    }
                });
            }



            //Paging
            self.page = ko.observable(0);
            self.noOfPages = ko.observable(0);
            self.nextPage = function () {
                if (self.page() < (self.noOfPages()-1)) {
                    self.page(self.page() + 1);
                    self.GetClass(self.page());
                } 

            };

            self.prevPage = function () {
                if (self.page() >= 1) {
                    self.page(self.page() - 1);
                    }

            };

            self.currentPage = ko.computed(function () {

                return self.TourSeriesDepartures().slice(self.page() * 10, (self.page() * 10) + 10);
            });

            self.noOfPages = ko.computed(function () {
                return Math.ceil(self.TourSeriesDepartures().length / 10);
            });

            // returns a list of numbers for all pages
            self.PageList = ko.computed(function () {
                if (self.noOfPages() > 1) {
                    return Array.apply(null, { length: self.noOfPages() }).map(Number.call, Number);
                }
            });

            self.goToPage = function (page) {
                self.page(page);
            };

            // determines if page # is active returns active class
            self.GetClass = function (page) {
                return (page == self.page()) ? "active" : "";
            }

        }




        $(document).ready(function () {

                vm = new viewModel();
                ko.applyBindings(vm);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have been an oversight on the grid creator's part. The way the code is set up the templates are directly bound to the selected item so any changes happen to the original model in real-time. There are a couple of ways to handle this, but given this particular example code the easiest thing to do is to create a backup of the item or the item's values on edit, and then restore them in the cancel function.

Here's one way to do that by creating a clone of the item and splicing it back into the item list to replace the modified one.

```
self.edit = function (item) {
    var clone = new State(item.id(), item.name(), item.shortName());
    self.selectedBackup = clone;
    self.selectedItem(item);
};

self.cancel = function () {
    if(self.selectedBackup){
        var item = self.selectedItem();
        var index = self.list.indexOf(item);
        self.list.splice(index, 1, self.selectedBackup);
    }
    self.selectedItem(null);
};
```

**Edit:**

In your code example the knockout context is different for the edit function than it is for the cancel function. You're also using selectedItem to refer to only the first departure in the selected row's departures array, but the edit button seems to refer to the entire group with a rowspan. Therefore in order to cache/restore the data being modified I would set the selectedItem to the entire departureGroup instead of the departure.

```
self.templateToUse = function (item) {
    return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editTmpl' : 'itemsTmpl';
};

self.edit = function (item, event) {
    var departureGroup = ko.contextFor(event.target).$parent;
    self.selectedItem(departureGroup);
    self.selectedItemCache(ko.mapping.toJS(departureGroup));
};

self.cancel = function (item) {
    if (self.selectedItemCache) {
        var departureGroup = ko.mapping.fromJS(self.selectedItemCache());
        var index = self.TourSeriesDepartures.indexOf(departureGroup);
        self.TourSeriesDepartures.splice(index, 1, departureGroup);
    }

    self.selectedItem(null);
};

self.save = function () {
    var item = self.selectedItem().Departures()[0];
...
```

Here's a working fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/3e9g0ros/](http://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/3e9g0ros/)

Comment: So my UI is bound to a child element(that's 2 level deep) in a nested collection. What would be the best way to splice to the "item " here? e.g. Level1, level 2, level 3 and item in my case is a row from level 3.

Comment: @user8808262 How does your edit function work? Does it have a reference to the model you're editing?

Comment: Yes I have a reference to level 2 (which contains array as level 3) and I need to update/cancel a value in level 3 .

Comment: @user8808262 I can't really picture what you mean. Can you edit your question to include an example?

Comment: Also I am mapping my VM using the mapping plugin dynamically.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped. I am new to knockout but is there a better/ideal way to do this? How would you typically design an inplace editable grid?

Comment: @user8808262 The design of the grid itself isn't a problem it seems like a good way to do it. There are ways to set up the underlying data that makes editing and reverting changes easier though. They do require some additional setup up-front. Take a look at http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Comment: What would I need to do if I need to edit at the level of "Tour 1 001" in the same code above. e.g. I need to change "Tour 1 001" to "Tour 1 111".

Comment: @user8808262 You should make it so the knockout context being edited is for a Departure instead of a Group. Get rid of the array[0] hacks and make proper edit templates for each departure.